# Usage of instanceof <pattern> in NetBeans 11.3 + OpenJDK 14

Tags: java, instanceof

After OpenJDK update to 14, the `instanceof` grammar was extended, so now we can use patterns: `RelationalExpression instanceof Pattern`. More info [here](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305). In NetBeans 11.3 I noticed the hint `instanceof <pattern> can be used here` near this method:

```
public String getTLSCipherSuite() {
    if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
        return ((SSLSocket) socket).getSession().getCipherSuite();
    }
    return null;
}
```

If I change reference type to pattern, I see NetBeans error:

```
public String getTLSCipherSuite() {
    if (socket instanceof SSLSocket sslSocket) {//<--- ")" expected
        return sslSocket.getSession().getCipherSuite();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Perhaps it's NetBeans bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JDK 14 feature can only be used if NetBeans 11.3 itself is running on Java 14 javac, not the nb-javac packaged with NetBeans 11.3. The java compiler's --enable-preview flag must be set also. See https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb113/index.html for details.  Of course, running NetBeans on javac instead of nb-javac means losing the nb-javac advantages.  See the links in https://blogs.apache.org/netbeans/entry/what-s-nb-javac-in for a discussion of the trade-offs.  The instanceof  syntax is still listed as a preview feature in JDK 15, so there is no guarantee it won't change in future Java versions.